# Mongo: Negative array references with indexed elements possible?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, indexing

I have added some array data to a Mongo DB using PyMongo. I've also created indexes for the array elements. The general approach is shown below.

```
data = [
    {"d": ["a", "b", "c"],},
    {"d": ["a", "c", "b"],},
    {"d": ["b", "a", "c"],},
]

my_collection.insert_many(data)
my_collection.create_index('d.0')
my_collection.create_index('d.1')
my_collection.create_index('d.2')
```

The last element in the arrays can be matched by running,

```
[x for x in my_collection.find({"d.2": "c"})]
```

As I understand things, the below command will show that the indexes are being used.

```
my_collection.find({"d.2": "c"}).explain()
```

I would like reference array elements with negative integers. For example,

```
[x for x in my_collection.find({"d.-1": "c"})]
```

The above command doesn't work. However the following equivalent command will produce the desire results.

```
[x for x in my_collection.find({"$expr": {"$eq": [ { "$arrayElemAt": [ "$d", -1 ] }, "c" ] }})]
```

However, running,

```
my_collection.find({"$expr": {"$eq": [ { "$arrayElemAt": [ "$d", -1 ] }, "c" ] }}).explain()
```

seems to indicate that indexes will not be used. Is there a way to use both negative array references and indexes?

Comment: it will not understand the negative array index, you have to give the exact array index number. or just create an index in the whole array field `.create_index('d')`.